# Best method to upload a file and then grab it back down with wget on another linux box?

Tags: dropbox, upload

I've been using dropbox's public folder to upload small files I want uploaded to my server via the wget command. Is there a better faster method than this without setting anything up? Is there an online service for this kind of thing?

Comment: What's wrong with installing Dropbox on both machines and making a private folder synchronised across the two systems? This is one of the things Dropbox was designed to do.

Comment: This was the first Google hit when I look for how to upload to dropbox with wget, could you share your command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're accessing your server, but the easiest way would just be to copy the files directly.

If you're using SSH, for example, you can just use scp or rsync to copy files directly from your workstation to the server.

For example if you'd connect to a server like this:

`ssh myname@serverurl`

You can copy a file by using:

`scp mylocalfile.txt myname@serverurl:/path/to/place/file/`

scp is great for just quickly copying a file or two over, while rsync is a great utility to keep a folder in-sync between two locations (among many other great uses).